# Sum of dynamic input fields? jQuery

Tags: jquery, sum, live, multiplication

I'm working on a form that calculates using multiplication and addition, but I can't seem to get the pieces to fall together correctly....

http://jsfiddle.net/cSfYE/

```
$('.qty').on('keyup', function() {
var sum = 0;
$("tbody tr").each(function(i,o){
    total = parseInt($(o).find(".qty").val(), 10) * parseInt($(o).find(".price-integer").val(), 10);
    if(!isNaN(total) && total.length!=0) {
        $(o).find(".install-total").val(total);
        sum += total;
    }
});
$("#total-equipment").val(sum);
});
```

When the user types in a quantity, say 2 in the first column, that should multiply by the figure in the fourth column (3,000) and be outputted into the **Install Total** column.

Then all the numbers in the Install Total column need to be added up and outputted in the **Total Equipment Cost** input field.

And finally, the **+ Installation** figures need to add up.

And all this has to happen after the user enters a quantity, which that part works. Yay.

---

I can't seem to get the syntax right or something! I've been looking at stackoverlow.com's posts for the past few days and nothing is working, so I'm hoping someone could throw me a bone and help me out. I really do appreciate your time.

Comment: `$(o).find(".qty").val()` is one issue, the td doesn't have a value. Try `$(o).find("input.qty").val()`. You're making the same mistake when you get the price.

Answer (score 5):

Problem rises in your selectors within row. You are referencing the `<td>` classes, not the inputs within them

This works, but might alos consider adding class to the inputs instead

```
 total = parseInt($(o).find(".qty input").val(), 10) * parseInt($(o).find(".price-integer input").val(), 10);
```

**[DEMO Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/cSfYE/1/)**

EDIT: addiitonal note - removed the test for length since integer doesn't have length

Comment: Thank you for that! I really appreciate it. It worked just fine. 

One more thing -- I'm trying to get the + Installation part to work. I updated the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cSfYE/1/

So, if a quantity is filled out in the first three fields, then add up the Installation cost (which is a hidden input field). I thought what I did was right, but it's not working.

Thoughts?

Comment: not seeing any hidden field...where is it? Also why can't you just add it in the `if( !isNaN)`

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, Sorry I just added it. http://jsfiddle.net/cSfYE/3/ 

<input type="hidden" value="500" class="installation-quote" name="installation-quote">

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, it's a install per unit. I guess it would be the same code as the first one, but I'm not sure where to put it? Is "sum" a variable that I can change the name of?

Comment: a simple `if` to see if  install in row `if($(o).find(".installation-quote').length)` then do math and add to total